# Python pandas: Find a value in another dataframe and replace it

Tags: python, string, pandas, matching

I have two dataframes df_l (with 3000 rows) and df_s(with 100 rows) :
df_l

```
version|update_date
2.3.4| date1
3.4.5|date2
```

and df_s

```
version|release_date
    2.3.4| date1
    3.4.5|date2
    3.3.3|date3
```

I want to check if a version in df_l is in df_s, then I want to update the values in df_l.update_date to df_s.release_date. Here is my code

```
df_l.ix[df_l['version'].isin(df_s['version']),'update_date'] = df_s['release_date']
```

but the updated values in df_l.update_date are wrong I am guessing that the matching is not taking place correctly. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with inner join `how='inner'` which is by default. Also you can omit `on` if in both `DataFrames` are only 2 columns and one of them is same in both:

```
print (pd.merge(df_l, df_s))
  version update_date release_date
0   2.3.4       date1        date1
1   3.4.5       date2        date2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am checking if for instance 2.3 from df_l is in df_s which then would cover for instance 2.3.1 etc.

Comment: I am only on phone to Sunday. But I think you can create `Series` from `df_s` by `s=df_s.set_index('version')['release_date']` and then map `df_l` by it. `df=df_l.set_index('version').map(s)`. Then get NaN when no match so I think need `df=df.combine_first(df_l)`. It is untested but I hope I help you.

Comment: I think you need `[]` like `df=df_l.set_index('version')['update_date'].map(s)`. In previous comment it is wrong.